# Palindrome Stack

Tags: java, stack

I wrote this method to check to see if a words is a palindrome, but when it is a palindrome it keeps returning false

public boolean isPalindrome(String s){

```
    int i;
    int n = s.length();
    Stack <Character> stack = new Stack <Character>();

     for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++) 
         stack.push(s.charAt(i));
        if (n%2 == 1)
            i++;


     while(!stack.empty( )) {
         char c = stack.pop( );
         if (c != s.charAt(i));
        return false; 



     }
     return true;



}
```

Comment: properly indenting your code would really help you to understand

Comment: Note that `for (anycondition) doSomething(); doOtherThing();` is complety different from `for (anycondition) { doSomething(); doOtherThing(); }`

Comment: Agree with @sleepToken, you may want to see Java Conventions https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf. Although they are more than 20 years old, they are not outdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're not using `{` `}` brackets. Try to learn proper Java conventions early.

```
if (c != s.charAt(i)); // <- this semicolon is your problem
return false;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (c != s.charAt(i)) {
  // Do nothing
}

// Do this no matter what
return false;
```

Furthermore, the logic on your for-loop may be flawed for similar reasons. Remove your semicolon, and better yet, practice always using brackets:

```
if (c != s.charAt(i)) {
  return false; 
}
```

@jhamon also points out that you never actually increment `i` in your while loop:

```
while(!stack.empty( )) {
  char c = stack.pop( );

  if (c != s.charAt(i)) {
    return false; 
  }

  i++;
}
```

Comment: what about  `i` value that never change?

Comment: @ChrisAgbemabiese did you rememeber to remove the `;` after your `if` statement and replace it with `{` `}` brackets?